# Unicode Characters do not properly show when received on client

Tags: java

I have a string that includes a character `string ="\u2663\"` 
among others.
I send the string over a socket using the printwriter and read with buffered reader:

`PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(c.clientSocket.getOutputStream(),true);`
`out.println(string)`

`BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(mainSocket.getInputStream()));`
`in.readLine()`

When the code is run in eclipse, it renders properly but when testing it via executable jar, the unicode character above shows a "?".

I feel like this is an encoding issue but can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: Why doesn't it feel like a font issue? Have you checked the font you're using where you're running your app can display that symbol?

Comment: I did test that out as well but I don't think its font related because it renders when run in eclipse and because if i just set the string on the client it renders properly. The only issue is when it goes through the socket.

Comment: I had tried that before posting but the character is still rendering as a "?". I think \u2663 is UTF-16 but I'm not too familiar with encoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The socket is transmitting bytes, not chars. The strings you are sending are being converted to bytes and back again, but with a default encoding assumed. The reason that this has worked in your IDE and not outside it is that different default encodings are being used.

You should explicitly use a suitable encoding (say, UTF-8) on both sides of the socket, something like this

```
new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(mainSocket.getInputStream()),StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(c.clientSocket.getOutputStream(),StandardCharsets.UTF_8),true)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response and this is indeed the correct answer. I thought I had tried this but I must have missed a few printwriters which caused issues. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure I know what's going on although I still need to implement a workaround.

To use the unicode character above, I switched the eclipse text file encoding from the default (Cp1252) to UTF-8. However, when running the jar, I'm pretty sure it is using the default Cp1252. I get the same result when I change the eclipse setting back to default.

Because PrintWriter uses the default character encoding, I'm going to have to find a way to output in UTF-8 or force the JRE to override the default and use UTF-8.

Comment: My theory is confirmed. Running from command line with -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 works but it doesn't seem like eclipse can export a runnable jar with that setting